# Facebook Like button not displayed

Tags: facebook-like

On the www.edwardrose.com website, we have numerous 'like' buttons for various apartment communities - but for one community, the 'like' button is not displayed.

here is an example page where the 'like' button is displayed:

http://www.edwardrose.com/pms/prop.asp?p=F&propid=75

and here is the page where the 'like' button is not displayed:

http://www.edwardrose.com/pms/prop.asp?p=F&propid=87

I've tinkered with this and if I modify only the Facebook page reference within the iFrame URL ('href=www.facebook.com%2FWindemereApartments'), I can get the 'like' button to display.  If I simply remove the trailing 's', replacing 'WindemereApartments' with 'WindemereApartment', the button is displayed.

We would appreciate any help you can provide in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Neither http://www.facebook.com/windemereapartment nor 
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Windemere-Apartments/301147187069 seem to be reachable – when I try to access those URLs, I’m redirected to the FB home page.

And looking up the page name or id in the Graph API Explorer does not give any results either.

Are you *sure* this page exists, and under this name …?

If so, any restrictions on it maybe, regarding viewer location or something else?

Comment: The facebook page is here:
https://www.facebook.com/WindemereApartments
I mentioned 'windemereapartment' only because the 'like' button is displayed if I use anything other than 'windemereapartments' (with the 's').

Comment: Again – this link too redirects me straight to the FB home page.